# Is it possible to initiate a remote repository on GitHub from the Git Bash command line?

Tags: git, github

If it is not possible, is there any way to do it without entering the browser and manually creating one, which then has to be synced to the local one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible if you use Github's CLI tool, [gh](https://cli.github.com/), with [gh repo create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create). You'll have to install the tool first.  There's no need for `curl`

Running `gh repo create` will create a new repository interactively. The command has flags that allow cloning the new repo (`--clone`) or create the new repo from a local folder (`--source`) and even push immediately (`--push`).

For example:

```
gh repo create my-project --private --source=. --push
```

[gh auth login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) will use the browser to login and store a token locally so you don't have to authenticate every time.

Comment: Simple and straight to the point - thanks! Can I fetch the URL from the newly created repo in the GitHub CLI in any way so I can paste it directly into Git Bash?

Comment: `gh` is a command-line tool which means you're already inside your shell when you use it. Whether that's Git's bash, wsl, Powershell or zsh doesn't matter. The new remote repository will be your local repository's `remote`. You can use `gh repo view` to view the repository's information, including its URL